# Home page does not display correctly in firefox 14.0.1

Tags: html, css, firefox

For some reason my web page is not display correctly in Firefox version 14.0.1. It is displayed correctly in IE9, Safari, chrome.  A friend of mine also said he experienced the same as me.

In Firefox if I zoom out or in the layout changes. But then the YouTube video begins to smear and pixelate. I asked a friend to check Firefox on their computer and the same thing happens.

http://wwww.streetstyles4all.co.uk/images/screen_shot.jpg

The screen shot from top left shows how the page loads.  Top right shows after I zoom in or out, and bottom left is after I scroll up and down.

HTML:

The HTML for the section in question is:

```
 <div id="homewallcontainer">

                <div id="homesidenavcontainer">

                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/23/850302323.js"></script>
                </div>

                <div id="newsletterblurb">
                <p>
                Learn everything you need to get yourself going in the world of street dance, tips, facts, what to wear, music, videos and more.  Just fill in the form above - simple!
                </p>
                </div>  

                <div id="contentcontainerhome2">
                   <h1>Street Styles 4 All is the place to be for street dance! With classes, DVD's that are sold worlwide, dancers for hire, streetwear...find out why you should choose Street Styles 4 All:
                   </h1>
                            <div id="homess4atrailer">
        <iframe width="466" height="302" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QyhgZ6I_DHo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>


           </div>


    </div>
```

The CSS is:

```
#homewallcontainer {
background: url("images/wall.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
height: 542px;
margin-top: -1px;
width: 960px;
}

#homesidenavcontainer {
float: left;
margin-left: 41px;
margin-top: 110px;
width: 253px;
}

#homesidenavcontainer {
float: left;
margin-left: 41px;
margin-top: 110px;
width: 253px;
}

#contentcontainerhome2 {
float: right;
margin-right: 17px;
margin-top: 46px;
width: 528px;
}

#homess4atrailer {
margin-left: 56px;
padding: 38px 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Well, this is how websites behave. Sorry, but that's the truth.

"If I zoom out or in the layout changes. But then the YouTube video begins to smear and pixelate"

This is a youtube thing, has nothing to do with CSS.

Comment: Thanks Panique.  I understand.  Can you explain the layout issues though?  Would you put it down to the way websites behave?

Comment: Thanks, but on firfox the standard page load produces errors, and it is only when I resize the page that the page looks the way it is meant to.  If you go to firfox and reload the page you will see that there are a few boxes not where they are meant to be - frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

First: Your question/problem is extremely unclear. You don't have resizing issues, you just have a messed up website that's "looks correct" when you resize, right ? Is that what you want to say ?

You problem is: The site is build by amateurs. There are a lot of layout issues, but there's a simply solution:

Remove the position:relative; of #indexwrapper in ss4a4.css, around line 250+ !

Comment: Hi.  You were right.  That worked!  So my site was built by amateurs?  Could you give me some examples of how you know?  It is hard to spot unless you know what you are looking for, and it will help me find more suitable people in teh future.  Thanks for the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the fault in Firefox seems to be the use of the HEIGHT attribute.  It was applied to 2 divs, and after removing the HEIGHT and POSITION:RELATIVE attributes, replacing with FLOATS, MARGINS and PADDING to create the layout of all the divs and nested divs in the section in question corrected the firefox issue.

That section of the site was carelessly written!